# Using a for loop with an index, parsing to separate lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a question that I have found an answer to, but the way in which it's coded seems a bit wieldy and a bit resource -heavy. Wanted to see if there was an approach that I conceptually think should work, however was unable to code properly.

The issue is with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as reqs

pagetoparse = 'https://fbref.com/en/squads/986a26c1/Northampton-Town'
page = reqs.get(pagetoparse)
status = page.status_code
parsepage = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

playerlist = []
positionlist = []
agelist = []

# Create playerlist - unique instances
findplayers = parsepage.find_all('th',attrs={"data-stat":"player"})
    for player in findplayers:
        addplayer = player.find_next('a').get_text()
        if addplayer not in playerlist and addplayer != 'coverage note':
            playerlist.append(addplayer)

# Create positionlist - non-unique
findinfo = parsepage.find_all('td',attrs={"data-stat":'position'})
    for position in findinfo:
        addposition = position.get_text()
        if addposition != 'coverage note':
            positionlist.append(addposition)

# Create positionlist - non-unique
findinfo = parsepage.find_all('td',attrs={"data-stat":'age'})
    for age in findinfo:
        addage = age.get_text()
        if addage != 'coverage note':
            agelist.append(addage)
```

Currently what I am doing is this, which works, however the problem is that I'd prefer to run the entire data-stat options in an index:

toparse = ['player','position','age'] etc.

However where I cannot get this to work, is then adding these individual index members to their respective lists. I can construct a for loop that does this, but they all end up in the same indexes. Can you help with getting the list to also change to the next, when running the data-stat variables within a list of its own? I.e the code swaps the list from playerlist to position list etc?

I've already managed to run the code separately to achieve this. However it lacks flexibility, and I'd say becomes a bit too long to manage.

Comment: Can make a dictionary of `{option : corresponding_list}`. Thing is if your lists are separate variables there is no point of only putting 'options' in a list. Putting them in a list serves a purpose of easily changing set of options but as you still have to maintain separate lists for them, that advantage is voided. Do both or leave as is is my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `find_next` function to get next element, [more details](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as reqs

pagetoparse = 'https://fbref.com/en/squads/986a26c1/Northampton-Town'
page = reqs.get(pagetoparse)
parsepage = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
playerlist = []
findplayers = parsepage.find_all('th',attrs={"data-stat":"player"})

for player in findplayers:
    playerdict = {}
    addplayer = player.find_next('a').get_text()
    if addplayer not in playerlist and addplayer != 'coverage note':
        playerdict['player'] = addplayer
        position,age = player.find_next('td'),player.find_next('td')
        while True:
            position = position.find_next('td')
            if position.has_attr("data-stat") and position['data-stat'] in 'position':
                playerdict['position'] = position.get_text()
                break

        while True:
            position = position.find_next('td')
            if position.has_attr("data-stat") and position['data-stat'] in 'age':
                playerdict['age'] = position.get_text()
                break

        playerlist.append(playerdict)

print(playerlist)
```

O/P:

```
[{'player':'David Cornell','position':'GK','age':'27'},{'player':'David Cornell','position':'GK','age':'27'},
{'player':'Aaron Pierre','position':'DF','age':'25'},{'player':'Sam Hoskins','position':'FW','age':'25'},
{'player':'David Buchanan','position':'DF','age':'32'},{'player':'Sam Foley','position':'MF','age':'31'},
{'player':'Ash Taylor','position':'MF,DF','age':'27'},{'player':'Jordan Turnbull','position':'DF','age':'23'},
{'player':'Andy Williams','position':'MF,FW','age':'31'},{'player':"John-Joe O'Toole",'position':'MF','age':'29'},
{'player':'Shay Facey','position':'DF','age':'23'},{'player':'Shaun McWilliams','position':'MF','age':'19'},
{'player':'Kevin van Veen','position':'FW','age':'27'},{'player':'Matt Crooks','position':'MF,DF','age':'24'},
{'player':'Daniel Powell','position':'MF,FW','age':'27'},{'player':'Jack Bridge','position':'FW','age':'22'},
{'player':'Charlie Goode','position':'DF','age':'22'},{'player':'Hakeem Odoffin','position':'DF','age':'20'},
{'player':'Dean Bowditch','position':'FW','age':'32'},{'player':'Junior Morias','position':'FW','age':'23'},
{'player':'Jay Williams','position':'DF','age':''},{'player':'Joe Powell','position':'MF','age':'19'},
{'player':'Billy Waters','position':'MF,FW','age':'23'},{'player':'Marvin Sordell','position':'FW','age':'27'},
{'player':'Timi Elšnik','position':'MF','age':'20'},{'player':'Leon Barnett','position':'DF','age':'32'},
{'player':'Scott Pollock','position':'MF','age':''},{'player':'George Cox','position':'DF','age':''},
{'player':'Ryan Hughes','position':'MF','age':''},{'player':'Morgan Roberts','position':'','age':''},
{'player':'David Cornell','position':'GK','age':'27'},{'player':'David Cornell','position':'GK','age':'27'}]
```